# cookies are flawlessly stored locally but not in the deployed website

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js, session-cookies, express-session

hey guys am building a web site using reactjs for frontend and expressjs (nodejs) and passportjs (for authentication) for backend,

***FRONT-END***

login request:

```js
const handelSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.currentTarget).entries());

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_LINK}/admin/login`,
      formData,
      {
        withCredentials: true
      }
    )
    console.log(res.headers['set-cookie']);
    dispatcher(login(res.data));
    navigate('/');

  } catch (err) {
    
    console.log(err );
    let errorMessage = ""

    if(err.response)
      errorMessage = err.response.data.message
    else
      errorMessage = err.message
    
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return setRequestError(errorMessage);
    // return setRequestError(err)
  }
}
```

***BACK-END***

*passport initalization*:

```js
server.use(session({
    name: "merals.id",
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStorage({
        mongoUrl: process.env.DB_STRING,
        dbName: 'test',
        collectionName: 'sessions'
    }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 // for 1 month
    }
}));

require('./utils/passport');

server.use(passport.initialize());
server.use(passport.session());
```

*./utils/passport*:

```js
passport.use('admin-local',
    new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
        const resultUser = await User.findOne({
            $or: [{ username: username }, { email: username }],
        });

        if (!resultUser)
            return done(
                { message: "Invalid Credentials" },
                false,
                "Invalid Credentials"
            );

        if (validatePassword(password, resultUser.hash, resultUser.salt)) {

            if (!resultUser.confirmedEmail) {
                const result = await SendConfirmationEmail(resultUser.id);
                if (!result) {
                    return done(
                        { message: "something went wrong with email" },
                        false,
                        "something went wrong with email"
                    )
                }

                return done(
                    { message: "Please Confirm Your Email" },
                    false,
                    "Please Confirm Your E-mail"
                );
            }

            if(!resultUser.isAdmin)
                return done({message: "You Dont have access"}, false, "You Dont have access");

            return done(null, resultUser);
        } else
            return done(
                { message: "Invalid Credentials" },
                false,
                "Invalid Credentials"
            )
    })
)

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((userID, done) => {
    User.findById(userID)
        .then((user) => done(null, user))
        .catch((err) => done(err));
});
```

*Login router*

```js
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate('admin-local', {
    successMessage: "you have been succesfully connected",
    failureMessage: true
}), (req, res, next) => {

    const user = {
        id: req.user.id,
        name: {
            fName: req.user.name.fName,
            lName: req.user.name.lName
        },
        username: req.user.username,
        email: req.user.email,
        info: req.user.email,
        profilePic: req.user.profilePic,
        info: req.user.info
    }
    res.status(200).json(user);
})
```

---

***REQUESTS HEADER:***

```js
{
  "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en,fr-FR;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6",
  "content-length": "47",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "dnt": "1",
  "host": "sunglasses-seagull.cyclic.app",
  "origin": "https://www.floidenergy.tech",
  "referer": "https://www.floidenergy.tech/",
  "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not.A/Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"114\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"114\"",
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-64a31da7-35a7a43d2ae2d68c0c3068a2;Parent=fb7afead97ec1a8a;Sampled=1;Lineage=f123bae9:0",
  "x-forwarded-for": "197.205.126.161",
  "x-forwarded-port": "443",
  "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
}
```

***RESPONSE HEADERS***

```js
{
  "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "https://www.floidenergy.tech",
  "connection": "close",
  "content-length": "2241307",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "date": "Mon, 03 Jul 2023 19:12:41 GMT",
  "etag": "W/\"22331b-CLpDPVnd3WOVqtoEuFN3dmY7iMU\"",
  "set-cookie": "merals.id=s%3AkPWMaNf0mIMNBq3Y3GLJTfkaZyIS6MKI.i8rzrqpzCm7Mj2gozFlOvPDTpZe4Fzia%2BpSGMT%2BMDzk; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 02 Aug 2023 19:12:41 GMT; HttpOnly",
  "vary": "Origin",
  "x-powered-by": "Express"
}
```

---

the problem is that when am using the my website localy the browser store session cookie on login success,
however when i host it online (vercel fron-end & cyclic backend) the browser doesnt store session cookie at all

PS: when i do this
`console.log(res.headers['set-cookie']);`
at login response it print undefined

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, it should not log anything locally as well. Browsers should prevent client javascript from accessing `set-cookie` header. Also the cookie is `HttpOnly` so it is not accessible via `document.cookie`. As of why the cookie is not set on a cloud deployment, please check this https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/ looks like you have different sites on prod.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko can u explain me more please.